# Laravel4 init another Model from a Model

Tags: php, oop, laravel-4, eloquent

How do initiate model from model in Laravel 4. I try the following but without any success

```
namespace App\Models;

use \Httpful\Request;
use \RecursiveIteratorIterator;
use \RecursiveArrayIterator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as DB;

class Parser extends \Eloquent {

public function __construct(AffiApi $affiapi) {
    $this->affiapi = $affiapi;
    $url = "HTTP://some.com/xml/feed_config.xml";
    $xml = Request::get($url)->expectsXml()->send();
    $this->xml = $xml->body;
    }


    public function Test(){
       $api = new Api();
       //I get error Class 'App\Models\Api' not found 
    }
}


class Api extends Parser {
 }
```

How di i do it properly or what is the cleanest way to achive this

Comment: There is one little thing that seems to be a bit contradicting which is the class `Api` extending from `Parser` in which you use `Api`.

Comment: You should loose the `Api` extends from `Parser` this is impossible. Kind of the chicken or the egg story. And sits the `AffiApi` also within the `App\Models` namespace?

Comment: Yeah i made already I try to bring all the stuffs inside Parser. I thought that I can separate the codes a bit like that

Comment: Can you post the beginning snippit of your `AffiApi` model?

Answer (score 0):

The neatest and best practiced way to do this is by using a principle called dependency injection (DI). This way it is loosely coupled and it will also be possible to inject stub classes for unit testing.

```
class Parser extends \Eloquent {

    public function __construct(Api $api) {
       $this->api = $api;
    }

    public function Test() {
    }
}
```

Be sure to run `php artisan dump-autoload` from the root of your project after adding new classes.

Comment: Thank you is this a typo error  $this-api = $api; should not be  $this->api = $api; ?

Comment: I just try your suggested

Comment: I get an error Argument 1 passed to App\Models\Parser::__construct() must be an instance of App\Models\AffiApi, none given, called in /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/laravel/app/controllers/admin

Comment: I see, there is something going on with a namespace! That is the reason of the slash before `\Eloquent`. Can you post some more code?

Comment: If your class is not within a namespace you can loose the backslash.